# Configuring Watson for multiples intents?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I need a solution inside Watson Conversation, if the user types two or more intents, Waston will tell you that he can only ask one thing at a time. How to make?

**SOME EXAMPLE:**

I have 2 intents, just for give one example for my question...

- `#requestLunch` and `#requestPizza`.

If user type:

- I want **lunch** burger and I want **pizza**. (Have 2 *intents*)

I want to make Watson answer with:

- You can only request one thing at a time. Do you want Lunch or Pizza?

I try it but seems like does not work.

**Print:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no immediate way to do it. Try something like

```
<? intents[0].name=="Lunch" && intents[1].name=="Pizza" && intents[0].confidence > .4 && intents[1].confidence > .4)?>
```

note that the intents sum up to 1, so u need to be careful with the threshold.